# SELECT ALL FROM bogus_table LIMIT 0

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm not a developer but a system administrator,

I found this query `SELECT * FROM bogus_table LIMIT 0\G` in the *MySQL-slow-query.log* in the **production** server.

I asked the developer about this query and he has no idea where this query coming from.

Thank to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407365/mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-0x80004005-select-command-denied-to-use) i assume that `SELECT * FROM bogus_table LIMIT 0\G` is to clear the kill flag which mean this query will be trigger afterward if the previous query return an error.- **correct me if i'm wrong.**

**So here my question:** How do i find/trace what query that running is triggering this query to be executed afterward (Based on my above assumption) `SELECT * FROM bogus_table LIMIT 0\G` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on [this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89850), this is seen when a user account does not have `SELECT` privileges for a table. If the application is not logging when/where SQL errors are being encountered, then you may need to run through user account permissions with `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@...` to determine where the issue is coming from

Comment: @matigo I didn't think so that the case, because the user had been granted `ALL PRIVILEGES` on that database, plus the Bogus table is never existed to begin with.

Comment: Is it possible that  `bogus_table` is a (potentially a large) temporary table created in code? Have you searched the code repo? If you simply try to `SELECT` from a non-existent table, it'll fail instantly and won't reach the slow_query_log!

Comment: @Vérace No, it actually a SQL query that hard coded in the MySQL-driver and this query will trigger on certain circumstances. [ref](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/68c54371821c87ff40a773acc127ce357b46a5ae/Source/MySql.Data/datareader.cs)

Comment: Hmmm... looks like this is a C++ coding issue and not really a DBA one - it's just **possible** that someone here **might** know about this - but I think you'd be better off asking on the MySQL tool devel lists or similar?

Comment: @Vérace Thank you for the suggestion, i would try that. I will post here when i got the answer which SQL query inside my application that causing `bogus_table` query to be executed.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct - and I for one will upvote it when you solve the problem...

Comment: Turn on the General Log.  Later, when that happens, search it.  (Be sure to turn off the log -- it is a disk hog.)